# SQLite PDO fetchAll gives blank array though table has records

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Please look into the below code.
SQLite3
PHP - SQLite-PDO

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name IN (:v1, :v2, :v3)';
$statement = $connection->query($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':v1','manash');
$statement->bindValue(':v2','ram');
$statement->bindValue(':v3','rahim');

for($i=0;$i<$statement->columnCount();$i++){
    $statement->getColumnMeta($i)
}
```

Comment: Check for record in `employee table` in your sqlite!!

Comment: There are 7 records exist

Comment: does your php have pernmission to read the database file ? PDO do not throw excception by default

Comment: What is the name of your sqlite file???

Comment: Yes it has .. because it is working for a different table